# Unable to connect to Internet in OEL5 guest even though I can ping machine from host machine

Tags: linux, redhat, virtualbox, linux-networking

I have Oracle Enterprise Linux 5 as Guest on VirtualBox running on Windows 7 host using Bridged Network.

I have being trying to configure a static IP on OEL5 VM Guest at work, as previously the VMs were configured to work within my network at home. I found an unused IP (10.167.190.118)  by pinging IP address from the windows host machine. I made the following changes on the OEL5 guest:

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0**

```
# Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
BROADCAST=10.167.176.1 ##Default Gateway
HWADDR=08:00:27:DE:AF:6D
IPADDR=10.167.190.118 #IPADDR=192.168.1.149
NETMASK=255.255.240.0 ##Subnet Gateway
#NETWORK=192.168.1.0
ONBOOT=yes
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
10.167.190.118          oel5-11g.com
# ::1           localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 10.167.176.1
search localdomain
```

Now when I stop/start the network daemon, I can ping 10.167.190.118 from the windows machine and can SSH using Putty. However, I'm unable to connect to the internet within the OEL5 guest.

I updated the **/etc/sysconfig/network**

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
HOSTNAME=oel5-11g.com
GATEWAY=10.167.176.1
```

...but get the error

> Bringing up interface eth0: RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

when running the network start command.

I have tried googling the issue but have got as far as being able to SSH into OEL5 guest using Putty from host. What changes do I need to make to ensure I can connect to the internet via the OEL5 guest?

***Additional information:***

**ipconfig from host:**

```
Windows IP Configuration

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnec
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : uk.oracle.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : uk.oracle.com
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.167.190.117
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.167.176.1

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.231.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.233.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

**ifconfig from OEL5 guest**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:DE:AF:6D
          inet addr:10.167.190.118  Bcast:10.167.176.1  Mask:255.255.240.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:193187 errors:0 dropped:14987 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:697 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:23047971 (21.9 MiB)  TX bytes:82847 (80.9 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1256 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1256 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3085266 (2.9 MiB)  TX bytes:3085266 (2.9 MiB)
```

I'm new to Linux and Vitualbox with limited knowledge of networks so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`10.167.176.1` is not the broadcast address for `10.167.190.118/20`.

Use an IP calculator to check: http://jodies.de/ipcalc

You can just remove the `BROADCAST` line in the ifcfg-file, the system is smart enough to figure out everything with only a valid IP and subnet mask.

(PS: I'll assume you are not the network adminstrator. On his behalf, please either ask for a static IP or get your guest IP via DHCP. Your network admin will not be happy the day he gets an address conflict and has to track it down to a rogue VM running on your workstation.)